# How to let PYTHON server receive the geolocation from HTML and get weather data then send this data back to web?

Tags: python, json, http, server, response

This is my first question! And I'm absolutely new to do this. It's kinda individual project.
I want to build up a server with python for providing the weather data, the required functions are:

1. client can send geolocation(lat and lon) to server, so the server must receive those data.
2. Then after server receives those data(I think it's string), server will send a HTTP GET to Netatmo using API depending on those data, to get the weather data, then my server already transfer the json data to string which only contain temperature and humidity now :). (I have done it!) 
   The geolocation data is in []
3. And server sends temperature & humidity data back to client!

PS: client get geolocation by using HTML5 API. (I still working on it with jquery. But I think I should build up server first right? )

And now I stuck. No idea how to code the 'receive' and 'send back' part.

Any idea or code is awesome!! thanks :)
This is my code for server (python)

```
import socket
import requests
import json
from Chris import token #for access the token
HOST,PORT='',8888
listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listen_socket.bind((HOST,PORT))
listen_socket.listen(1)

print("Listenning on port %s" % PORT)

while True:
    client_connection, client_address = listen_socket.accept()
    request = client_connection.recv(1024)
    print(request)

r=requests.get('https://api.netatmo.com/api/getpublicdata?access_token='+token+'&lat_ne=**['+lat_ne+']&lon_ne=['+lon_ne+']&lat_sw=['+lat_sw+']&lon_sw=['+lon_sw+']&filter=TRUE') 
#lat_ne=str(lat+0.2), lon_ne=str(lon+0.2), lat_sw=str(lat-0.2), lon_sw=str(lon-0.2)

json_object = r.json() #json_object = dict

data1=json_object['body'][0]['measures'] 

data2 = sorted(data1.items())[0][1]['res']
#print(sorted(data1.items())[1])
#data3 = sorted(data1.items())[1][1]['res']
data2str = str(data2.values())
#data3str = str(data3.values())
datatemperature = data2str[14:18]
datahumidity = data2str[19:22]



http_response = " The temperature is " + datatemperature  + ". The humidity is " + datahumidity

client_connection.sendall(bytes(http_response.encode('utf-8')))
client_connection.close()
```

Comment: Any specific reason to use web sockets and not known frameworks such as `Flask` for example?

Comment: You should really try to limit your question to one issue only, and try to create a minimal example. This makes it easier for yourself to understand the different issues you're having, and also for people to help you on the individual topics. In this case, you already describe you have multiple smaller issues: - read out geolocation data in web site using HTML5 - send data to server - let server look up forecast and respond - handle response on client. Try solve these small issues step by step, you can find lots of info online about the separate steps. Good luck!

Comment: I just searched some tutorial in Google and Youtube and then code it... sorry I'm a newbie.  @Avihoo Mamka

Comment: Thanks man! you give me a good idea to solve problem! I'll not fail you:) hopefully @MichielB